# How to ignore shellcheck when using minted in sublime?

Tags: minted, sublime-text, chktex

I want to ignore `shellcheck` when writing a LaTeX document while using `minted` package. I know, when using `shellcheck` I can easily ignore warnings or errors globally by placing a line right at the beginning of the document. E.g.`# shellcheck disable=SC2148` to ignore an error for not giving a `shebang`.

Note, I am using sublime text on Mac. I furthermore installed `shellcheck`, `chktex` and `pygmentize`. (As there is also `chktex` written in the sublime status bar I don't know if this also plays into it)

A minimal working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{shell}
  ls -al
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

This complains for not mentioning a `shebang`.

If I do

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{shell}
  # shellcheck disable=SC2148
  ls -al
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

everything works just fine. But as I am having numerous `minted` environments I want to disable errors globally.

**EDIT**

Of course I could just disable `shellcheck` for the whole project. This is done by editing the corresponding project file

```
{   
    "folders":
    [
     ...
    ],
    "SublimeLinter":
    {
        "linters":
        {
            "shellcheck": {
                "disable": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am searching for a way to disable it on a per file basis, not on project basis.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure what's the purpose of running `shellcheck` over a LaTeX file. When you include the scripts in the LaTeX document, you will already have checked them.

Comment: Actually me neither. I am using `shellcheck` for my scripts. I was also surprised when I learned that `shellcheck` is applied kind of automatically to `minted` environment. I actually never specified to run it on my latex files.

Comment: I have the impression that Sublime Text tries to outsmart users.

Comment: I updated my post, to specify the problem further and added a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a sort of interference between two well-intentioned features. On the one hand, `SublimeLinter-shellcheck` will run `shellcheck` against almost all code that Sublime scopes as being shell script. This allows the linter to support non-standard shell syntax and shell syntax embedded in other files. On the other hand, the LaTeX syntax scopes `minted` blocks to the appropriate syntax so you get syntax highlighting while editing the file.

As you discovered, you can use the `"disable"` setting to disable the longer altogether, but you have a couple of other options. The first is to change the `"selector"` setting from the default of `"source.shell - source.makefile - source.shell.fish"` to `"source.shell - source.makefile - source.shell.fish - text.tex"`. This will stop `shellcheck` from being run on any TeX / LaTeX document. The other option is to change the `”excludes"` setting to something like `"*/*.tex"`, which should stop it from running on any file with the extension `.tex`. Either of these settings can go in the same place you put the `"disable"` setting or in your user settings, etc.

Comment: Thanks. We are almost there. With this I can exclude certain files. However, as you mentioned, this configuration need to be placed either in the project configuration or in the `SublimeLinter` configuration under `linters`. Are you aware of a way to just add a line to the beginning of the document I want to exclude from being shellchecked?

Comment: @Stefan: AFAIK, no, there’s nothing like that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. As it seems that we have covered all options, I'll accept it as an answer to my question.